# How to assert tooltip text through Selenium and Python unittest

Tags: python, selenium, assert, python-unittest, webdriverwait

I'm learning Selenium. Why this simple test is failing?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import unittest


class ToolTipTest (unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_tool_tip(self):
        driver = self.driver
        frame_elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name("demo-frame")
        driver.switch_to.frame(frame_elm)
        age_field = driver.find_element_by_id("age")
        ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(age_field).perform()
        tool_tip_elm = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-tooltip-content")))

        # verify tooltip message
        self.assertEqual(
            "We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.",
            tool_tip_elm.text)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Sometimes it gives

```
AssertionError: 'We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.' != "ThemeRoller: jQuery UI's theme builder app
lication"
- We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.
+ ThemeRoller: jQuery UI's theme builder application
```

Sometimes:

```
AssertionError: 'We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.' != "That's what this widget is"
- We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.
+ That's what this widget is
```

So the error isn't always the same. Sometimes it pass. It looks that it select a random popup. [Here's](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) the page to test. I'm using python 3.6 selenium 3

Edit: also how can I check (in Firefox Developer Tools) the html code of the tool tips to look class, id etc? When I select the code the tooltip desappear and the code too...

Comment: That's weird if you are running the code you posted and getting different results. The only thing I could think of is maybe when the page first loads, it cycles through the different tooltips and that's why you get different results. You might try adding a wait for invisible for the tooltip before you hover, then hover, and then check the tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. The element with *tooltip text* was not the correct one. To assert the *tooltip text* you can use the following optimized solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  import unittest


  class ToolTipTest (unittest.TestCase):
      def setUp(self):
          self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
          self.driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/")
          self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
          self.driver.maximize_window()

      def test_tool_tip(self):
          driver = self.driver
          WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.demo-frame")))
          age_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#age")
          ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(age_field).perform()
          tool_tip_elm = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ui-helper-hidden-accessible div:not([style])")))
          self.assertEqual("We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.", tool_tip_elm.text)

      def tearDown(self):
          self.driver.quit()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main(verbosity=2)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  test_tool_tip (__main__.ToolTipTest) ... ok

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ran 1 test in 17.618s

  OK
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Add some (other dynamic) wait before row

```
tool_tip_elm = ...
```

because your code waits until element is visible, but popup text is changed afterwards. So your test is often faster than web page change.

Working version (but with static wait):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import unittest
import time

class ToolTipTest (unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_tool_tip(self):
        driver = self.driver
        frame_elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name("demo-frame")
        driver.switch_to.frame(frame_elm)
        age_field = driver.find_element_by_id("age")
        ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(age_field).perform()
        time.sleep(3)
        tool_tip_elm = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-tooltip-content")))

        # verify tooltip message
        self.assertEqual(
            "We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.",
            tool_tip_elm.text)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: I have this html code: `<div class="ui-tooltip-content">We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.</div>`. What condition should I wait for? I can't think to nothing... Also why my popup text is changed? It shouldn't. Thank you

Comment: Wait for desired text to spawn, not just any text. If not in given time (10 seconds), test should fail. I don't know if there exists selenium condition for this. In our framework, this is usually done in while cycle.